# How to apply a function in each column of a data frame?

Tags: r

I have the following data frame with 345 rows and 237 columns in R:

```
snp1 snp2 snp3 ... snp237 
0 1 2 ... 0
0 1 1 ... 1
1 1 2 ... 2
1 0 0 ... 0
... ... ... ...
2 2 1 ... 0
```

I want to apply the following function in each column:

```
D=(number of 0)/(number of rows)
H=(number of 1)/(number of rows)
R=(number of 2)/(number of rows)
p=D+(0.5*H)
q=R+(0.5*H)
```

Lastly, I want to store the "p" and "q" for each snp in a vector. This function have calculate "p" and "q" for each snp in a single command of R. It is possible?

The output is:

```
snp1 snp2 snp3 ... snp237
p1 p2 p3 ... ... p237
q1 q2 q3 ... ... q237
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does your expected output look like?

Comment: I expect a vector with p and q for each snp (column).

Comment: Try `f1 <- function(x) {H <- mean(x == 1);list(p = mean(x == 0) + (0.5 * H), q = mean(x == 2) + (0.5 * H))}; library(dplyr); df1 %>% summarise_all(f1) %>% unnest`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#DATA
set.seed(42)
d = data.frame(snp1 = sample(0:2, 10, TRUE),
               snp2 = sample(0:2, 10, TRUE),
               snp3 = sample(0:2, 10, TRUE))

#Function    
foo = function(x){
    len = length(x)
    D = sum(x == 0)/len
    H = sum(x == 1)/len
    R = sum(x == 2)/len
    p = D + 0.5 * H
    q = R + 0.5 * H
    return(c(p = p, q = q))
}

#Run foo for each column   
sapply(d, foo)
#  snp1 snp2 snp3
#p 0.35 0.4  0.35
#q 0.65 0.6  0.65
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option with `tidyverse`.  Create a function (`f1`) based on the logic in OP's code to return a `list` of length 2, then use that in `summarise_all` to apply the function on each of the columns of dataset

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
f1 <- function(x) {
              H <- 0.5 * mean(x == 1)
              list(list(p = mean(x == 0) + H,
                  q = mean(x == 2) + H))
                  }
df1 %>%
   summarise_all(f1) %>% 
   unnest
#  snp1  snp2  snp3
#1 0.75 0.625 0.375
#2 0.25 0.375 0.625
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(snp1 = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 1L), snp2 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
 0L), snp3 = c(2L, 1L, 2L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
  -4L))
```